# PHP Not inserting POST data into database

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

I am trying to insert data from an automated POST request into a database, but it is not inserting it and is throwing no errors. (None in error log)
Code:

```
<?php
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $content);
if(isset($r[1])) {$r = explode($end, $r[1]);
return $r[0]; } return''; }

file_put_contents("outputfile.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"), FILE_APPEND );

$cip = $_POST['ipaddr'];
$cid = $_POST['id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', '********', '*******');
$sql = "INSERT INTO slso (asid, ips) VALUES ('$cid', '$cip')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql); mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

The content of outputfile.txt is this:

```
ipaddr=192.168.0.4&id=8&endipaddr=***.**.230.62&id=8&end
```

However no data is ever inserted into the database. Am I making a simple mistake that I am not noticing?

Comment: Does the query fail? Check the return value of `mysqli_query`.

Comment: @Halcyon The request is sent by an automated script, so I cant read what the page says

Comment: You only have 3 parameters for your connection. `mysqli_` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php requires 4; are you not choosing a database? Once you've done that, do `mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything also.

Comment: Plus, seeing `ipaddr=192.168.0.4&id=8&endipaddr=***.**.230.62&id=8&end` suggests a GET method, yet you're using two POST arrays. Your question is unclear. Post your HTML form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was going off of W3schools example, it did not have the database selected. that was the issue. The data is being sent via a remote script.

Comment: Problem solved then, yes?

Comment: I've made an edit to John's answer to that regard. You can accept it to close the question.

Comment: Yes, problem solved.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read in from `php://input` once in PHP versions prior to 5.6.

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/ro/wrappers.php.php)

> Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.

As a work around you can extract those values from `php://input`:

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
file_put_contents("outputfile.txt", $post, FILE_APPEND );

parse_str($str, $output);

$cip = $output['ipaddr'];
$cid = $output['id'];
```

---

Another thing is, you only have 3 parameters for your connection. `mysqli_` requires 4.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Once you've done that, do `mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: It is able to write many requests into the text file from php://, and I dont even use that for actually getting the variables

Comment: I tried that code, and it has the same effect. Writes to outputfile.txt but doesnt put it in the database